# PDFBox pdf to image generates overlapping text

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

For a side project I started using PDFBox to convert pdf file to image. This is the pdf file I am using to convert to image file https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf.

This is the code I am using. It is very simple code which calls PDFToImage. But the output jpg image file looks really bad with lot of commas inserted and some overlapping text.

```
    String [] args_2 =  new String[7];
    String pdfPath = "C:\\bitcoin.pdf";
    args_2[0] = "-startPage";
    args_2[1] = "1";
    args_2[2] = "-endPage";
    args_2[3] = "1";
    args_2[4] = "-outputPrefix";
    args_2[5] = "my_image_2";
    //args_2[6] = "-resolution";
    //args_2[7] = "1000";
    args_2[6] = pdfPath;
    try {
        PDFToImage.main(args_2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the logging outputs (maybe you need to activate logging in your environment). you'll see many entries like these (generated using PDFBox 1.8.5):

```
Jun 16, 2014 8:40:43 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont drawString
Warnung: Changing font on <t> from <Century Schoolbook Fett> to the default font
Jun 16, 2014 8:40:43 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont drawString
Warnung: Changing font on <S> from <Times New Roman> to the default font
Jun 16, 2014 8:40:46 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont drawString
Warnung: Changing font on <c> from <Arial> to the default font
Jun 16, 2014 8:40:52 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont drawString
Warnung: Changing font on <i> from <Courier New> to the default font
```

So PDFBox uses different fonts than the fonts indicated by the PDF for rendering the text of it. This explains both the *lots of commas inserted* and the *overlapping text*:

1. different fonts may have different encodings. It looks like your sample PDF uses an encoding which has a comma where the default font assumed by PDFBox has a space character;
2. different fonts have different glyph widths. In your sample PDF the different glyph widths cause overlapping text.

This results in
[image: First page of sample document rendered using PDFBox 1.8.5]

The reason for all this is that PDFBox 1.8.x does not properly support all kinds of fonts for rendering. You might want to try PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, the new PDFBox currently under development, instead. Be aware, though, the classes for rendering have been changed.

### Using PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Using the **current** (mid-June 2014) state of PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT you can render PDFs like this:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(resource, null);
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<PDPage> pages = catalog.getAllPages();

PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++)
{
    BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImage(i);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("bitcoin-convertToImage-" + i + ".png"));
}
```

The result with this code is:
[image: First page of sample document rendered using the current PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]

Other `PDFRenderer.renderImage` overloads allow you to explicitly set the desired resolution.

**PS:** As proposed by [Tilman Hausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) you may want to replace the `ImageIO.write` call by

```
    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image, "bitcoin-convertToImage-" + i + ".png", 72);
```

`ImageIOUtil` is a PDFBox helper class which tries to optimize the selection of the `ImageIO` writer and to add a DPI attribute to the image file.

If you use a different `PDFRenderer.renderImage` overload to set a resolution, remember to change the final parameter `72` here accordingly.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. I will try with the snapshot version.

Comment: I recommend to use ImageIOUtil.writeImage() instead of ImageIO.write(), which sometimes creates slightly smaller files and writes the dpi value into the image.

Comment: Just to be sure, take the snapshot from June 14. The last from June 17 is a major improvement, but I haven't yet tested it with my test files.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I just tested using the June 17 updates. The page 1 of the sample PDF still looks good. On the following pages some graphic lines are missing, though, at least using the code above, i.e. using default resolution.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Testing at scale 5 (360 dpi) some (but not all) of the missing lines appear.

Comment: @mkl: this is a known problem, see PDFBOX-1288 :-( Btw the tests of the June 17 update are OK. (PDFBOX-2104)

Comment: @mkl: on your "1. different fonts may have different encodings" - PDFBox correctly interprets the font's `/ToUnicode` to convert from arbitrary binary value to a Unicode character, but the value gets 'decoded' again somewhere else, as if it never was decoded in the first place. Look at the ToUnicode table, and you'll see.

Comment: Pdfbox interprets **ToUnicode** during text extraction, but this question was about page drawing while using font replacements. As far as I remember testing this issue, Pdfbox for that did not employ the **ToUnicode** mappings.