# PDFBox Extract Image with Text

Tags: java, pdfbox

I’m trying to convert a PDF into an image.

```
ImageView iv = convertBufferedImage(page.convertToImage());
```

The convertBufferedImage method looks like:

```
 private ImageView convertBufferedImage(BufferedImage bf)
{
    WritableImage wr = null;
    if (bf != null)
    {
        wr = new WritableImage(bf.getWidth(), bf.getHeight());
        PixelWriter pw = wr.getPixelWriter();
        for (int x = 0; x < bf.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bf.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                pw.setArgb(x, y, bf.getRGB(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
    return new ImageView(wr);
```

For some PDF documents it works fine.
With the following document I don’t get the hole page with its containing text.

[image]

The image shows the PDF with missing text.

If I try to get native  text with:

```
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
pdfAsText = pdfStripper.getText(document);
```

It works fine and I can print it to the console.

I also get these information out of PDFBox:
Okt 02, 2014 1:29:58 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
Information: unsupported/disabled operation: i

I hope anybody can help.

Comment: Which PDFBox version do you use? There are many deficiencies in the page rendering code in the 1.8.x versions which have been fixed in the current 2.0.0 development SNAPSHOTs; especially PDFBox used to not properly render characters from certain types of fonts.

Comment: For another sample of rendering issues look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24238070/1729265).

Comment: The "information" about "unsupported/disabled operation" is irrelevant here, the problem is what mkl says. There's trouble with embedded fonts in the 1.8 versions.

Comment: I used version 1.8.7. Your tip was right. Now I'm using versino 2.0.0-Snapshot and it works fine. Thank you!